# Error when generating line Chart, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Here is the problem reproduced. You can see the error when running it and opening the console.
http://plnkr.co/edit/WC5TLIMENHtLcPF7T8uK?p=preview

I get a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
```

Within nvd3.js on the function defined in line 6125. [Link the the source](https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/v1.8.1/build/nv.d3.js). Few lines of the function below:

```
function chart(selection) {
    renderWatch.reset();
    renderWatch.models(lines);
    if (showXAxis) renderWatch.models(xAxis);
    if (showYAxis) renderWatch.models(yAxis);
    console.log(selection);
    selection.each(function(data) {
    ...
```

Which looks to be defining the structure of the chart. However I am still a beginner with this library so I would very much appreciate your help in how to solve this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

1.) Your data is in the wrong format, it should be an array of objects, not just a single object:

```
var data = [{
  "key": "test",
  "values": [{
    "val": 56.00,
    "timestamp": "2015-11-08T18:10:36"
  }, {
    "val": 88.45,
    "timestamp": "2015-11-08T18:11:36"
  }, {
    "val": 120.71,
    "timestamp": "2015-11-08T18:12:36"
  }, {
    "val": 30.04,
    "timestamp": "2015-11-08T18:13:36"
  }, {
    "val": 55.11,
    "timestamp": "2015-11-08T18:14:36"
  }, {
    "val": 88.31,
    "timestamp": "2015-11-08T18:15:36"
  }, {
    "val": 90.09,
    "timestamp": "2015-11-08T18:16:36"
  }]
}];
```

2.) The `nv.addGraph` takes a function as an argument but you are calling the function.  Should be:

```
nv.addGraph(generateLineChart);
```

Update plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EQ5zmpos2DSRUnmtR3xs?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much! A follow up: what if I wanted to pass in arguments into my `generateLineChart` function (like axis labels, formatting, etc), how might I go about doing that if the `nv.addGraph` takes a function? I checked the source for addGraph and it doesnt seem like it provides a way to do that.

Comment: @M.g. Just create a function that returns a function.  See updates [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EQ5zmpos2DSRUnmtR3xs?p=preview)